# Get ID of new record in function trigger before insert on postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I am making a function trigger that will be executed before insert new record in some table, this function trigger will insert the new record in another table with some values of the first insert. I need to execute before insert because I need the last record in the first table to compare with some fields of the new record.

The problem here is, that I can find how to get the Id of the record that will be inserted cuz the record doesn't exist yet.

I am thinking user a sequence to get the next id that will be generated, but I don't know if these cause problems if there are more than one user writing to the database at the same time.

This is my function PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mydb.mytriggername()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN  
    IF (
        SELECT tvalue FROM mydb.myTable WHERE type = NEW.type AND sb = NEW.sb AND st= NEW.st order by id DESC LIMIT 1
       ) <> NEW.tvalue THEN
        INSERT INTO mydb.anotherTable( type, date, desc, tp, sb, st, ref)
        SELECT 'tc', NEW.date, 'newdesc', NEW.type, NEW.sb, NEW.st, CONCAT('{"id_ref":', NEW.id, '}');
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Notice that I need use it on `CONCAT('{"id_ref":', NEW.id, '}');` but as I said before, I don't have the id because the new records it doesn't insert yet.

Do you have any approach to solve my problem?

Comment: have a look if the table is using serial filed, in this case you have a sequence and can get next value.   if not you can try to use max(id)

Comment: Yes @Adam, this field is using serial id, My concern is what happen if there are another transaction just in he same second of the first transaction start. Is there the possibility that the transaction save the id of the third record instead of the current transaction?

Comment: @Adm, it's seems that works well but when the query return an empty result set the comparations not works "Empty resultset <> NEW.tvalue"

Comment: @Adam, effectively there are a problem with this approach, when you excecute nextval, it get the next id and save the value on the sequence. So when the trigger excecute again nextval and the id returned is not already the same.

Answer (score 2):

you don't reveal your trigger code, so I'm not sure this is the case, but below is an example of using `NEW` before `INSERT`

```
t=# create table ta1(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table ta2(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create function taf() returns trigger volatile not leakproof as $$
begin
if NEW.i > 0 then insert into ta2 values (NEW.i); end if;
return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# create trigger tg before insert on ta1 for each row execute procedure taf();
CREATE TRIGGER
t=# select * from ta2;
 i
---
(0 rows)

t=# begin; insert into ta1 select 5;
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from ta2;
 i
---
 5
(1 row)

t=# end;
COMMIT
```